# How to stop rotation in parent ViewController when unwound from Segue from a child UIViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, screen-rotation

I have two UIViewControllers - ViewControllerA and ViewControllerB (these are not in NavigationViewController hierarchy).
ViewControllerA implements the following method:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

On a button click on ViewControllerA, ViewControllerB is called. Now if we change the orientation of ViewControllerB to Landscape and move back to ViewControllerA, the orientation of ViewControllerA is changed to Landscape mode.

How does one prevent the same from happening?

Comment: Try `UIViewController.attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation` when displaying controller with fixed orientation.

Comment: Thanks @Andy - Let me check that